# Vista: want it to reboot and restart my apps nightly

Tags: windows-vista

I'd like Vista to reboot everynight.  Ideally, after it rebooted it would open up all my apps so that when I log back in in the morning I don't have to restart everything.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Schedule-a-task) that executes the following command: `shutdown /r /f /t 0`

Restarting your applications should be a matter of just [adding them to your start-up folder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Run-a-program-automatically-when-Windows-starts).

Comment: Will application in my start-up folder be started when the system reboots, or only when I login for the first time after it reboots?  I'd really like them to be started up before I log in (not sure if this is possible in Windows) as a couple of the apps take a while to start up.  If it isn't possible, I'll still accept your answer.

Comment: Every time, when you log in. It's not possible to do that prior to login, an option could be to [automatically login](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905) and create a batch file that automatically locks your account afterwards...